# Hosting in South Africa vs Europe, or using Azure South Africa

Tags: azure, hosting

My client has been hosting using an IIS-based server in South Africa, because it gives a clear speed advantage to the customer base which is largely South Africa-based.  However, while travelling in Japan and Australia, I've noticed the huge deterioration in speed when accessing the site.

Up till now I've avoided pushing the site onto a European cloud host because of the definite deterioration (we've usually used West Europe with other clients), since the sea cables run to Europe I believe.

Recently Microsoft launched what appear to be data centres in South Africa, but I'm not sure what the full capabilities are.

If our customer base was split 80-20 between South Africa and the rest of the world outside of Africa, what would be the optimal location to host and would the Azure expansion to Africa influence that choice, and in what way?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to have a presence in more than one location and direct users to the location most appropriate for their connectivity. So you can have an instance in SA Azure, and another in West Europe.

Comment: That would come with the burden of synchronizing data right?

Comment: Replicate or partition data where required by your design. Some systems perform adequately with the application tier far from storage / database / APIs, some do not.